# Offgrid backup AC power option

Tags: power, generator, power-engineering

I’ve been building an off grid home for a few years - recently moved in full time.  Living in VT, with limited solar, we depend on a Honda EM6500SX 240v generator to occasionally recharge 20 batteries via an XW4024 Inverter/charger.  I’m thinking ahead to options available for future generator failure and would appreciate help.

We also have a nice little EU2000 generator for camping, but it only supplies 110 v.  I assume that’s no help recharging batteries since system designed for 240.  BUT, I’m wondering if, just to “get by,” could I bypass my inverter - and supply one half of my house panel at a time, with the small generator?

My hope is that I could “unplug” from my failed 240 volt 6500w generator and, alternatively, plug into my own special female connector - which I would equip with two male “pigtails(?),” making a sort of “splitter.”  Each of the male connectors would use ground and white - with one using red and one using black.  In my naive theory, I could use existing house switching to bypass my 240v inverter - and deliver 110v EU2000 power to one side of the house panel at a time.  Which circuits get power would be determined by which plug I activated by generator.  [Not perfect - but helpful.]

Abandoning battery system for a while, this might allow me to “get by” since we would temporarily have no 240v need.  Am I missing some problem, please?

Comment: "existing house switching " is a little vague.   Is this a 3-way power transfer switch?

Comment: Electrician originally installed two nominal  60 amp 120/240 circuit breakers side-by-side in the distribution box next to inverter/charger.  They are “linked” mechanically by a metal device which only allows power direct from generator to house panel when the generator to inverter breaker is “off.”  I just checked, and flipping them turned off all house power until I started generator.  Manual transfer option.

Comment: Is that still too vague?  Looks like:
SQUARE D QOU2DTILA : CIRCUIT BREAKER ACCESSORY INTERLOCK ATTACHMENT
Technical Description:
Mechanical Interlock Attachment Type; Qou Series Low Ampere Miniature Circuit Breaker Used on; RoHS Compliant; Mounting Location Left Side of Circuit Breaker
UPC: 78590137638

(Took pic but can’t see how to upload)

Comment: Fine .   Seems too easy and obvious.  Will try.